# Having trouble writing the function property of a struct correctly in Rust

Tags: function, struct, rust

I'm trying to instantiate an instance of a struct (`Struct1`) in an array. Instances of `Struct1` store a function (`method`) that takes a generic type `T` for a parameter. The following code is how I attempted to do this:

```
struct Struct1<T> {
    method: fn(T)
  }
  
fn main() {
    let arrOfStructs = [
        Struct1 { 
            method: fn(char) {
                let a = char; //this does nothing useful, just a mock function
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

But I get the error following errors:

```
error: expected expression, found keyword `fn`
 --> test.rs:8:21
  |
7 |         Struct1 {
  |         ------- while parsing this struct
8 |             method: fn(char) {
  |                     ^^ expected expression

error[E0063]: missing field `method` in initializer of `Struct1<_>`
 --> test.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         Struct1 {
  |         ^^^^^^^ missing `method`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0063`.
```

I'm assuming the second error listed is present simply because the instance's method wasn't properly instantiated, because of the first listed error. But I can't figure out what the first error is trying to say. As far as I know, Rust instantiations can be implicitly typed. I can't figure out what else might be the problem though. Could you guys help me out with this one? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to create an anonymous function (a closure) in Rust is not what you tried. Rather, it is:

```rust
|arg1, arg2, arg3, ...| body
```

Where `body` can be any expression, including a block (`|| { body }`), parameters can have type annotations (`|arg: Type| {}`) and the closure may specify the return type explicitly using `->`: `|| -> ReturnType {}`.

In your example,

```rust
fn main() {
    let arrOfStructs = [
        Struct1 { 
            method: |char: YouHaveToSpecifyTheTypeHere| {
                let a = char; //this does nothing useful, just a mock function
            }
        }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to supplement the answer:

There are two ways to construct a function pointer, one is constructing via an existing function,
and the other is using a closure(anonymous function) that doesn't capture any environmental
variables

```rust
fn add_one(x: usize) -> usize {
    x + 1
}

// using an existing function
let ptr: fn(usize) -> usize = add_one;
assert_eq!(ptr(5), 6);

// using a closure that does not enclose variables
let clos: fn(usize) -> usize = |x| x + 5;
assert_eq!(clos(5), 10);
```

[link to the official doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html#safety)